# Getting a 7 by 1/2 a reroll

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is my first time on this site so bear with me:

I am trying to get a result that is 7 or as close to 7 as possible from rolling 2d6. If I were to roll 2d6 and not get a 7, and I were to re-roll one of those d6s, what would be odds I would get a 7? Would those odds be better or worse than keeping what I initially rolled.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "as close as possible" mean?  Obviously your odds of getting a $7$ improve if you have the option of rolling one of the die again.  After all, if you had a $7$ the first time then you just wouldn't exercise the option.  But...is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get exactly the right value on the second roll, since the die you're leaving alone plus the die you're rerolling have to add to $ 7 $, and there's exactly one way to do that in each case. So, the probability of getting the right value is $ 1/6 $:

$$ \begin{align}
     \mbox{die left alone } &\& \mbox{ die rerolled} &(\mbox{probability})
\\   1 \ &\& \ 6 &(\mbox{1/36})
\\   2 \ &\& \ 5 &(\mbox{1/36})
\\   3 \ &\& \ 4 &(\mbox{1/36})
\\   4 \ &\& \ 3 &(\mbox{1/36})
\\   5 \ &\& \ 2 &(\mbox{1/36})
\\   6 \ &\& \ 1 &(\mbox{1/36})
   \end{align}
$$

$ 6 $ total cases with a combined probability of $ 1/6 $. That's the same probability as on the first roll of both dice.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of your game are not clear.

I assume that if you roll a $7$ the first time you don't reroll.

Now you want to decide whether it's better to reroll if you don't get a $7$ the first time.

If your total the first time is $6$ then at least one of the dice is not a $1$. Keep that one. Rerolling the other you will get a total of $6$ (again) or $7$ or $8$ with probability $1/6$ each. That means the probability that you are worse off (total more than $1$ away from $7$) is $1/2$. Is that a risk you want to take for the $1/6$ chance to get $7$ exactly?

Can you use the same logic to work out the probabilities for the other totals?